# Acces app.settings Node.JS in a file without req object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `node.js/express.js` for my app.

In my `app.js`, I define several configuration variable, such as my database object:

```
app.set('db', mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.host,
        user: config.user,
        password: config.password,
        database: config.database,
        timeout: 15000
}));
```

I also define a `CronJob`, which will use a function located in another file (`gmail.js`) :

```
new CronJob('1 * * * * *', function () {
        gmail.fetchMail(config); // Config is well-defined
}, null, true);
```

In `gmail.fetchMail()` I call another function (`process()`) which will save stuff in my `DB`.

Here, I of course need to access my `DB` object defined in `app.js`. But

1. I have no request object in `gmail.js`, thus I can't just do `req.app.settings.db`
2. I don't want to export my `app.js` and then require it in `gmaiul.js` to access `DB`, since I think it is a very bad practice.

So, how could I possibly can, from `gmail.js` access my `DB` object defined in `app.js` by using the settings method: `app.set(db), [...]` ?

Comment: Just wrap your db code in another module like `db.js` and require it both from `app.js` and `gmail.js`. Nothing wrong with that

Comment: That what I did before, but my manager change it. Don't know really why. I'll re-change it :)

Comment: I'm guessing (s)he wasn't expecting to need the connection outside of the routes..